# How to add columns into tab? CSS, HTML

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I can't work with columns in the tab div. When I pull it out of the tab div it's working. What am I missing?

example code: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FZJ3933552IJ

How it looks like:
[image]

How it should look like:
[image]

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: _"When I pull it out of the tab div it's working"_ - Are you sure about that? https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FZJ3PI8WKG2T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

add this bootstrap link in your page. thanks

Answer (score 2):

there is no CSS for "col" and "row", these are used in bootstrap.

Add the line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```